# expected primary-expression before ' arrayName '

Tags: c++

I dont undersatnd why this expected primary-exception errors are there!!! ... :

```
Running /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:50:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘arrayHelpfull’
          std::string arrayHelpfull[3],
                      ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:51:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
          double arrayHelpfullPoints[3],
          ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:52:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘arrayNone’
          std::string arrayNone[3],
                      ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:53:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
          double arrayNonePoints[3],
          ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:54:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘arrayHarmfull’
           std::string arrayHarmfull[3],
                       ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:55:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
           double arrayHarmfullPoints[3],
           ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:61:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘arrayHelpfull’
        std::string arrayHelpfull[3],
                    ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:62:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
        double arrayHelpfullPoints[3],
        ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:63:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘arrayNone’
        std::string arrayNone[3],
                    ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:64:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
        double arrayNonePoints[3],
        ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:65:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘arrayHarmfull’
         std::string arrayHarmfull[3],
                     ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:66:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
         double arrayHarmfullPoints[3],
         ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:74:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘arrayHelpfull’
        std::string arrayHelpfull[3],
                    ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:75:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
        double arrayHelpfullPoints[3],
        ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:76:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘arrayNone’
        std::string arrayNone[3],
                    ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:77:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
        double arrayNonePoints[3],
        ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:78:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘arrayHarmfull’
         std::string arrayHarmfull[3],
                     ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample.cpp:79:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
         double arrayHarmfullPoints[3],
         ^
```

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>


void printingItems(


    std::string arrayHelpfull[3],
    double arrayHelpfullPoints[3],
    std::string arrayNone[3],
    double arrayNonePoints[3],
     std::string arrayHarmfull[3],
     double arrayHarmfullPoints[3],
    std::string option

    ) {
    std::cout << option << std::endl;

}


int main(){
  std::string arrayHelpfull[3] = {"fruits", "soda" , "candy"};
  double arrayHelpfullPoints[3] = {20.4,50.2,30.0};

    std::string arrayNone[3] = {"chair", "shoe" , "pencil"};
  double arrayNonePoints[3] = {0,0,0};

    std::string arrayHarmfull[3] = {"meth", "dirtyneedle","ninga"};
  double arrayHarmfullPoints[3] = {-20,-50,-30};

  int userChoice = 0;
    while (userChoice != 4) {

      std::cout << "1 - Just Plain Items"
            << std::endl
            << "2 - Helpfull Items"
            << std::endl
            << "3 - Harmfull Items"
            << std::endl
            << "4 - Quit"
            << std::endl;

        std::cin >> userChoice;

        switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:
            printingItems(
            std::string arrayHelpfull[3],
            double arrayHelpfullPoints[3],
            std::string arrayNone[3],
            double arrayNonePoints[3],
             std::string arrayHarmfull[3],
             double arrayHarmfullPoints[3],
            "Plain"
         );
            break;
        case 2:
        printingItems(
        std::string arrayHelpfull[3],
        double arrayHelpfullPoints[3],
        std::string arrayNone[3],
        double arrayNonePoints[3],
         std::string arrayHarmfull[3],
         double arrayHarmfullPoints[3],
        "Helpfull"
        );

            break;
        case 3:

        printingItems(
        std::string arrayHelpfull[3],
        double arrayHelpfullPoints[3],
        std::string arrayNone[3],
        double arrayNonePoints[3],
         std::string arrayHarmfull[3],
         double arrayHarmfullPoints[3],
        "Harmfull"
        );

            break;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need an [mcve] and a question.

Comment: Why are you using `,` after each variable declaration in `printingItems` and not `;`?

Comment: @computerfreaker It is a function parameter list.

Comment: @NathanOliver Odd formatting got me. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @computerfreaker i just couldnt understand why this error is in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printingItems(
            std::string arrayHelpfull[3],
            double arrayHelpfullPoints[3],
            std::string arrayNone[3],
            double arrayNonePoints[3],
             std::string arrayHarmfull[3],
             double arrayHarmfullPoints[3],
            "Plain"
         );
```

Is not how you call a function and pass variables to it.  You just need to give the name of the variable to the function.  What you are doing is trying to redeclare variables in a function call.  All of your function calls should look like

```
printingItems(arrayHelpfull, arrayHelpfullPoints, arrayNone,
              arrayNonePoints, arrayHarmfull, arrayHarmfullPoints, "Plain");
```

You also need to use some consistent indentation.  Having indentation that changes makes code very hard to read.

Comment: Omg Thanks a lot! Wow, got my nerve away! cant accept in 7min